# Oracle Forms: Printing Without Dialog Box

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms, oraclereports

Our application runs on oracle 10g. When we want to print a report after filling the oracle form fields we do the following process:
1. save the file (when it is saved it opens in a new tab)
2. hit control+p (print preview is shown)
3. hit enter (command goes to printer)
Now we want to directly send command to the printer so that the print preview is not shown at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this by using the `ORARRP` utility. Unfortunately, you must have access to Oracle Support to view this support document.

Note that the bottom of the support document specifies a change to `orarrp.ini` to prevent the print preview from showing.

https://support.oracle.com/rs?type=doc&id=277431.1